# can this image be a css box-shadow gradient?

Tags: gradient, css

can I make this using box-shadow? right now it's an image but I'm wounding if this can be done with css box-shadow.

[image: the shadow I want]

Comment: Have you tried something?? If yes, provide jsFiddle link containing your code.

Comment: of course I tried to do it before asking,but with no luck

Comment: Have you considered applying the gradient to a container with the whitespace/content nested as a div inside? Just use some light padding on the container to show the gradient as if it is the border for the whitespace. Codepen: http://cdpn.io/gyxGs

Answer (score 6):

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sinhayash/7dPnQ/1/

```
.class {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;        
border-top: 3px solid rgb(16, 130, 253);
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(179, 216, 255);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(rgb(16, 130, 253)), to(rgb(179, 216, 255)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, rgb(179, 216, 255));
    background-image:
        -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(16, 130, 253), rgb(179, 216, 255)),
        -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(16, 130, 253), rgb(179, 216, 255));
    background-image:
        -o-linear-gradient(rgb(16, 130, 253), rgb(179, 216, 255)),
        -o-linear-gradient(rgb(16, 130, 253), rgb(179, 216, 255));
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(rgb(16, 130, 253), rgb(179, 216, 255)),
        linear-gradient(rgb(16, 130, 253),rgb(179, 216, 255));
    -moz-background-size: 3px 100%;
    background-size: 3px 100%;
    background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Working on firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this can be done with `box-shadow` but it can be done with a combination of borders and background gradients.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pFxPg/3/)

```
div { 
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    border-top: 5px solid #4672bb;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #b8c9e5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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),
    url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4672bb, #b8c9e5);
    background-image:
        -moz-linear-gradient(#4672bb, #b8c9e5),
        -moz-linear-gradient(#4672bb, #b8c9e5)
    ;
    background-image:
        -o-linear-gradient(#4672bb, #b8c9e5),
        -o-linear-gradient(#4672bb, #b8c9e5)
    ;
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(#4672bb, #b8c9e5),
        linear-gradient(#4672bb, #b8c9e5)
    ;
    -moz-background-size:5px 100%;
    background-size:5px 100%;
    background-position:0 0, 100% 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

SVG's generated with the fantastic [ColorZilla Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Updated with IE9 support. For IE9 you need to use SVG's. See the link I added at the bottom

Comment: out of subject ,To use box-shadow , you need to know the height and generate a hudge shadow (3rd numerical-value)  wich you reduce (4th numerical value)to feet. possible but total nonsence indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the image as a border-image:
 <s>http://jsfiddle.net/RRpcD/</s>  jsfiddle dislike this image ? what about codepen : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/Awihd

```
.gradient-border {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 4px 4px 3px;
    -moz-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/O87Qx.png) 2 4 4 3 stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/O87Qx.png) 2 4 4 3 stretch;
    -o-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/O87Qx.png) 2 4 4 3 stretch;
    border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/O87Qx.png) 2 4 4 3 fill stretch;
}
```